# How to extract specific text in between dash symbols starting from the right to the left

Tags: php, wordpress

I have text that looks like this :

```
This is some-text for - Extracted Text - random
This is-some-text for - Extracted Text - another random
This-is a third-text for - Extracted Text - more random
```

I want to extract `Extracted Text` from the texts in PHP.

I tried this.

```
$titleTrimd = explode('-', $title);
$TrimdTitle=trim($titleTrimd[1]);
```

The challenge I'm having is that it's picking the wrong text because of `[1]` not being definite. I need to extract from right to left for this to work (count the number of dashes from the right). This way I will always get the targeted text. This is because on the left of the extracted text, the number of the dash character changes and can be anything but on the right the number is static so checking from the right to the left will work. I just don't know how to go about this.

Please Help.

Comment: do you want to extract all the 'Extracted Text' entries from a string? Or what exactly? The question is very unclear to me

Comment: If the text looks like that, with spaces around the dashes for the text you want to get, you should be able to explode on `' - '` (with the spaces around the dash) and it should work.

Comment: Yes, I want to extract all the 'Extracted Text' but I can't specify the position directly without starting from the right to the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so by using `explode` and then extract the required value by specifying the position from the right as

```
<?php
function extractText($str)
{
    // Break the string into an array
    $exp = explode('-', $str);

    // `count` will return number of elements in an array.
    // Since array index starts from zero, to retrieve 2nd last element we need to use `-2`
    // Remove spaces at the start and end of the text by using `trim` function
    return trim($exp[count($exp) - 2]); 
}

echo extractText('This is some-text for - Extracted Text - random'); // Extracted Text
echo PHP_EOL;
echo extractText('This is-some-text for - Extracted Text - another random'); // Extracted Text
echo PHP_EOL;
echo extractText('This-is a third-text for - Extracted Text - more random'); // Extracted Text
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Samir. I have tried to implement it but seems something is wrong with my code. The text I wish to extract from is the post title so I am doing it this way. 
```<?php
$title = the_title();
$titleTrimd= explode('-', $title);
$Trimd = trim($titleTrimd[count($titleTrimd) - 2]);
echo $Trimd;
?>``` It appears something is off with my code.

Comment: Your answer is okay. I had challenges implementing in my particular case which (I acknowledge) I didn't mention. I changed the_title(); to get_the_title(); which then works for me. Thanks for the amazing answer! One final issue though, challenged with replacing the hyphen with the en dash. I just realized it wasn't a hyphen. Tried replacing with the en dash but it doesn't work. I have accepted your answer.

Comment: Changed the en dash to ```&#8211;```. That get's me sorted!